# requestImageForAsset always returns nil - even after checking for nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

So, I'm having a weird (and frustrating) issue.
I'm looping through an array of assets returned by an image picker:

```
let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
for asset in assets {
    var image = UIImageView?
    manager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: { (result, info) -> Void in
        if result == nil {
            print("Nil alert!")
            return
        }
        print("not nil")
        image!.image = result

    }
}
```

In the console I get the expected messages:

```
not nil
```

immediately followed by this message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I've been messing around with this for hours and I can't seem to figure out what exactly the problem is. If I try to print the `result` directly it says something like `<UIImage: 0x12f780a20>, {45, 60}`

Any help would be welcome :)

Comment: There are two optional values on that line, image and result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't setting anything to `image` after defining it, so it's going to be `nil` here:

```
 var image = UIImageView?
```

When you force-unwrap it with `!` here, you're hitting the runtime error:

```
 image!.image = result
```

Comment: That is so obvious it hurts. That's whats happen when you stare at something for too long. I'll accept this as the answer as soon as I can. Thank you!